# Is it possible to point to a class?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue application (a all-encompassing element with with several child components) to which I would like to add a night mode. I would like this night mode to be managed centrally, where the relevant styling would be applied to the elements which need to switch to night/day mode.

If I have an element (it is in the DOM as part of a component having been rendered, so not directly available to the parent component and therefore not bindable via `v-bind`)

```
<div class="night-day">hello</div>
```

and two classes

```
.night {
  background-color: black;
  color: red
}

.day {
  background-color: white;
  color: black
}
```

is it possible to have `night-day` pointing to either `day` or `night` (depending on some condition)?

Comment: how this condition will be? and why not simply switching between both classes depending on this condition

Comment: @TemaniAfif: the condition will be a `setInterval()` which ultimately triggers a message `$emit` to a common `Vue()` bus. I clarified why a direct binding is (AFAICT) is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the use of CSS variables that you change within your JS code (setinterval). Basically you will have something like this:

```
<div class="night-day">hello</div>


.night-day {
  background-color: var(--bc,black);
  color: var(--c,red)
}
```

And within your JS you will have something like this:

```
var bc= ["black", "white"]
var c= ["red", "black"]

....
document.querySelector('.night-day').style.setProperty("--bc", bc[i]);
document.querySelector('.night-day').style.setProperty("--c",  c[i]);

...
```

Where `i` is an index that you can change based on your conditions:

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was something I was considering too, in a possibly simpler form: to group all color management in one place and address the elements via their `id` and `document.getElementById()`. There would be two blocks, available though an `if`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach for solving the multiple themes problem would be to have a theme class modifier on the `body` tag and in your CSS, modify your subelements accordingly. Here's an example to clarify things up.

```
<body class="dark-theme">
    <div class="container">
        Content...
    </div>
</body>
```

---

```
.container {
  background-color: white;
  color: black
}

.dark-theme .container {
  background-color: black;
  color: red
}
```

Toggling `.dark-theme` on the `body`, in this case, would switch between the default theme and the dark theme.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `v-bind:class` ([Class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes)) from vue for this.
Like:

```
 <div class="static" v-bind:class="{ night: isNight, day: !isNight }"></div>
```

Comment: Please see my clarification about why I believe this is not doable in my case

Comment: Ok, maybe you could make a toplevel wrapping component? Otherwise i would choose the CSS variables approach.

Answer (score 1):

### Using event bus

You could use a [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) to bind a CSS class to a property, controlled by an event handler.

```
// MyComponent.vue
<template>
  <div class="daynightdemo" :class="{ night: isNight }">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { eventBus } from '@/eventBus'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isNight: false
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setNightDay = value => {
      this.isNight = value === "night";
    };
    eventBus.$on("nightDay", this.setNightDay);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    eventBus.$off("nightDay", this.setNightDay);
  }
}
</script>
```

You mentioned the event bus being periodically called from `setInterval`. In this example, the call would look like something like this:

```
// App.vue
export default {
  mounted() {
    let isNight = true;
    setInterval(() => {
      eventBus.$emit("nightDay", isNight ? "night" : "day");
      isNight = !isNight;
    }, LONG_INTERVAL);
  }
};
```

[demo with event bus](https://codesandbox.io/s/rwlz6p33n4)

### Using Vuex

Using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), the boilerplate would be somewhat simplified, obviating the need for event-callback registration and unregistration:

```
// MyComponent.vue
<template>
  <div class="daynightdemo" :class="{ night: $store.state.isNight }">
    <h1>isNight: {{ $store.state.isNight }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

// App.vue
export default {
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.$store.state.isNight = !this.$store.state.isNight;
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

[demo with Vuex](https://codesandbox.io/s/vv1yz7nwv7)